# Running MongoDB queries from AS3 client?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, node.js, mongodb, v8

Is it possible to run native Javascript functions for the mongo shell on server side from AS3 client AIR app?

I have a lot experience in running Javascript methods embedded/loaded on HTML where SWF is also embedded and I'm wondering if i can do a server side request to run Javascript methods residing on the server.

More specifically, Im interested in running commands on the mongoDB console built on V8 or similar.

For instance, on the official mongoDB website a console is embedded. I wonder if this console is actually connected to the server or is it just a mock?

I dont want to use node.js if I can use V8 or connect directly to the console, is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly to mongo using a lib like this one: https://code.google.com/p/jmcnet-full-mongo-flex-driver/

It's easy to use and lets you do most anything possible through the mongo console.